# How can I do a SQL join to get a value 4 tables farther from the value provided?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, inner-join

My title is probably not very clear, so I made a little schema to explain what I'm trying to achieve. The `xxxx_uid` labels are foreign keys linking two tables.

[image]

**Goal:** Retrieve a column from the `grids` table by giving a `proj_uid` value.

I'm not very good with SQL joins and I don't know how to build a single query that will achieve that.

Actually, I'm doing 3 queries to perform the operation:

1) This gives me a `res_uid` to work with:

`select res_uid from results where results.proj_uid = VALUE order by res_uid asc limit 1"`

2) This gives me a `rec_uid` to work with:

```
select rec_uid from receptor_results 
inner join results on results.res_uid = receptor_results.res_uid
where receptor_results.res_uid = res_uid_VALUE order by rec_uid asc limit 1
```

3) Get the grid column I want from the `grids` table:

```
select grid_name from grids 
inner join receptors on receptors.grid_uid = grids.grid_uid 
where receptors.rec_uid = rec_uid_VALUE;
```

Is it possible to perform a single SQL that will give me the same results the 3 I'm actually doing ?

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not limited to one JOIN in a query:

```
select grids.grid_name 
from grids 
inner join receptors
    on receptors.grid_uid = grids.grid_uid 
inner join receptor_results 
    on receptor_results.rec_uid = receptors.rec_uid
inner join results 
    on results.res_uid = receptor_results.res_uid
where results.proj_uid = VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select g.grid_name
from results r
join resceptor_results rr on r.res_uid = rr.res_uid
join receptors rec on rec.rec_uid = rr.rec_uid
join grids g on g.grid_uid = rec.grid_uid
where r.proj_uid = VALUE
```

> a small note about names, typically in sql the table is named for a single item not the group.  thus "result" not "results" and "receptor" not "receptors" etc.  As you work with sql this will make sense and names like you have will seem strange.  Also, one less character to type!